# Non degenerate critical points.

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $K$ be a compact subset of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $U$ be a neighborhood of $K$ and let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that all critical points of $f$ in $K$ have index $\ge \lambda_0$. If $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth funtion such that
$$ \left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_{i}} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} \right|< \epsilon $$ and
$$ \left|\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}- \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}\right|< \epsilon ,$$
for all $i,j \in [1,n]$ uniformly throughout $K$, for sufficiente small costant $\epsilon$, then alla critical points of $g$ in $K$ have index $\ge \lambda_0$.
Can you give me an example of functions $f$ and $g$ with these proprerties? (for example if $n=1,2$)

Comment: For any $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, the function $g = f$ satisfy the two inequalities you posed... Other simple examples include $g = f + v\cdot x$ where $|v|_{\infty} < \epsilon$ and $g = f + x^T A x$ where $A$ is a matrix with $\infty$-norm at most $\epsilon$ (for example, $A$ is the matrix with entries all $\epsilon/2$).

Comment: @WillieWong I'm looking for an explicit $f$ such that the index of $f$ in a compact is $\lambda_0 >0$...

Comment: Let $x_0 \in K$, let $f(x) = -|x- x_0|^2$. The only critical point in $K$ is at $x_0$, and it has Morse index $n$.

Comment: If you want to choose $0 \leq \lambda_0 \leq n$, just take $y\in K$ and $$f(x) = - \sum_{i = 1}^{\lambda_0} (x_i - y_i)^2 + \sum_{i = \lambda_0 + 1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2$$

Comment: @WillieWong Why $f(x)$ has Morse index $n$? $\frac{df}{dx}$ isn't a function...

Comment: $\partial f / \partial x_i = -2 (x_i - x_{0,i})$ which vanishes if $x_i = x_{0,i}$ or $x = x_0$. Similarly compute its Hessian. You'd find that the Hessian evaluated at $x_0$ is $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x_0) = -2\delta_{ij}$.